# Pythonic ways to use sorted function

Tags: python

During the lockdown, I have been following a python course on coursera. To sort a dictionnary keys by values, they use the following syntax :

```
occurence = {'E': 2, 'F': 1, 'B': 2, 'A': 2, 'D': 3, 'I': 2, 'C': 1}

y = sorted(occurence.keys(), key=lambda k: occurence[k])
```

The code is working like a charm, but I got trouble to understand the "why" of the syntax. In the python documentation, to sort a list of tuples, they use this code :

```
student_tuples = [('john', 'A', 15), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('dave', 'B', 10)]

sorted(student_tuples, key=lambda student: student[2])
```

As I understand it, **student** allow us to iterate over the tuple **student_tuples**. But in the case of the dictionnary, the logic doesn't seems to be the same. As **k** is the iterable, we can't iterate through occurence.keys() which is just a list of key, and not the dictionnary itself.

To keep the same logic as the one in the documentation, i'll tend to go on something like :

```
items = sorted(occurence.items(), key = lambda k: k[1]) #  k iterate over occurence.items()
y = [key[0] for key in items]
```

Definitively longer, but it's not a mind twister anymore (to my eye !)

What do you think about that ? I'm just beginning my python journey, but I'm really concerned about the readability of my code.

Thanks !

Comment: "To sort a dictionnary **keys** by values" (emphasis mine)  - that's exactly what it does, and it never pretended to sort the items. And of course you can iterate on the keys.

Comment: I think you need to reread the [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted) definition. `k` is _not_ the iterable! And yes, you can iterate through `occurence.keys()`, because as a `list` it is an iterable.

Comment: "As k is the iterable, we can't iterate through occurence.keys() which is just a list of key, and not the dictionnary itself." Huh? You can iterate through that just fine. I'm not sure why that bothers you. note, if you are using Python 3, *which you should be* `.keys` returns a set-like view, not a list. in any case, you can just do `sorted(occurence, ...)` because `dict` objects are directly iterable over their keys. So `sorted(occurence, key= lambda k: occurence[k])` works, or just `sorted(occurene, key=occurence.get)`

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed one crucial point.

When you do `sorted(iterable, key=func)`, the function needs to accept one argument which is **the elements from `iterable`**. The `key` is used by `sorted` to define the sorting criteria - when you don't want the default which is just the elements themselves. The `key` function is being called on each element from `iterable` internally, as part of the sorting algorithm.

So in the the tuples example, when you do `sorted(student_tuples, key=lambda student: student[2])` This basically means "*sort `student_tuples` according to the third element of each tuple*". The arguments being passed to the `lambda` are the tuples, and from each tuple the third (index `2`) element is used for comparing and deciding the order.

Back to the dict example, doing `sorted(occurence.keys(), key=lambda k: occurence[k])` means: "*sort the dict's keys, according to the value of each key in the dict*". Again, in this case the `iterable` is the keys, so the arguments to the `lambda` are the keys themselves. The `lambda` then returns the value associated with each key by accessing the dict (`occurence[k]`) and that is used to compare and sort **the keys**.

Yes, `lambda k: occurence[k]` is a different and confusing pattern compared to the more *"standard"* `lambda student: student[2]`, but that's part of learning - open yourself to new and challenging ways of using the tools a language has to offer.